# Balayage of measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Are there any references for that explains what a balayage of a measure is for people who are not already familiar with the concept? The reference I have found is *Logarithmic Potentials with external fields* from Saff and Totik but there its properties are stated and not really given the intuition behind the concept with a simple example.

Does anyone have a good reference for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a book '**Foundations of Modern Potential Theory**' by N. S. Landkof (translated from Russian by A. P. Doohovskoy).

There you may find better motivation and explanation.